# General-purpose mixed integer programming in R

Tags: r, optimization, discrete-optimization, integer-programming

I am finding out if there is any package that can do general-purpose mixed integer programming in R. I found some packages that can do integer programming, such as `ompr` and `CVXR`, but `ompr` only does linear programming and `CVXR` has a limited number of math functions allowed.

Suppose I want to maximize the loglikelihood of $X=(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_m)$ from a Binomial($N$, $p$) distribution on both $N$ and $p$, which is $\underset{N,0<p<1}{\rm max}\sum_{i=1}^m[log\binom{N}{x_i}+x_ilog(p)+(n-x_i)log(1-p)]$. Given $N$ should be integer, $p$ should be real, I am wondering how to maximize this objective function in R.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: For each $N$ there is a closed form solution for $p.$  Thus, you have a function of a single integer.  It can be extended to a function on a set of (positive) real values: analyze that extension to find a small set of plausible candidate solutions for $N$ (there will usually be just one or two) and then inspect them to find the global solution.  The `R` details of doing this are not on topic here.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, that's an interesting perspective! I can say that there is a way to solve this specific problem in `R`. Based on your answer, I think we can set up a set of integers for $N$, find the corresponding $p$, and then maximize the log likelihood to find the global solution.